# Calculate minimum distance in a straight line using BFS

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

Trying to solve [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/castle-on-the-grid) using BFS.

Problem Gist: Initial and final position is given for a [rook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_(chess)) placed in a matrix. You are required to find out minimum number of steps for rook to reach final position. Some position marked with "X" shouldn't be crossed, whereas "." are the allowable positions.

```
Matrix:
.X.
.X.
...
source position: 0,0
target position: 0,2
answer:3 (0,0) -> (2,0) - > (2,2) -> (0,2)
```

My solution basically does below:
I start doing BFS from source node and after I dequeue the node I am adding all the vertical and horizontal nodes in memory with the current distance of that node plus 1. After that I am checking if the destination node is present in memory and if it is present I am returning that distance.

This below solution is not working in some of the cases. Any suggestions?

```
def update_distance(memoize_dist, current, n, count, matrix):
  directions = [1, -1, 1, -1]
  current_x, current_y = current
  temp_x, temp_y = current
  for direction in directions:
    while temp_x < n and temp_x >= 0:
      temp_x += direction
      temp = (temp_x, current_y)    
      if temp_x >= n or temp_x < 0 or matrix[temp_x][current_y] == 'X':
        temp_x, temp_y = (current_x, current_y)
        break                   
      if temp not in memoize_dist.keys():
        memoize_dist[temp] = count
  for direction in directions:
    while temp_y < n and temp_y >= 0:
      temp_y += direction
      temp = (current_x, temp_y)
      if temp_y >= n or temp_y < 0 or matrix[current_x][temp_y] == 'X':
        temp_x, temp_y = (current_x, current_y)
        break       
      if temp not in memoize_dist.keys():               
        memoize_dist[temp] = count

def get_shortest(n, src, target, matrix):
    queue, memoize, memoize_dist = [], {}, {}
    queue.append((src[0], src[1], 0))
    memoize_dist[(src[0], src[1])] = 0
    while len(queue):
      x, y, count = queue.pop(0)
      cur = (x, y)
      if cur in memoize.keys() and memoize[cur] != -1:
        continue
      memoize[cur] = 1          
      update_distance(memoize_dist, cur, n, count+1, matrix)    
      if target in memoize_dist.keys():
        return memoize_dist[target]
      directions = [1, -1, 1, -1]
      for direction in directions:
        if cur[0]+direction < n and cur[0]+direction >= 0 and matrix[cur[0]+direction][cur[1]] != 'X':
          queue.append((cur[0]+direction, cur[1], memoize_dist[(cur[0]+direction, cur[1])]))
        if cur[1]+direction < n and cur[1]+direction >= 0 and matrix[cur[0]][cur[1]+direction] != 'X':
          queue.append((cur[0], cur[1]+direction, memoize_dist[(cur[0], cur[1]+direction)]))

n = int(input())
matrix = []
for i in range(n):
    matrix.append(input())
start_x, start_y, dest_x, dest_y = map(int, input().split(" "))
print(get_shortest(n, (start_x, start_y), (dest_x, dest_y), matrix))
```

Comment: Feel free for any queries.